# I have data at Store_Id, Date level and have to mark whether that store was visited or not week-wise using SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-science

I have Data at Store_Id, Date level as represented below:

| Store_Id | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2020 |
| 2 | 01-01-2020 |
| 3 | 01-01-2020 |
| 1 | 07-01-2020 |
| 3 | 07-01-2020 |
| 1 | 13-01-2020 |
| 2 | 13-01-2020 |

I want to convert the above table at Store_Id, week level and mark whether that store was visited or not.
Somewhat like represented below

| Store_Id | Week | Visit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | YES |
| 2 | 1 | YES |
| 3 | 1 | YES |
| 1 | 2 | YES |
| 2 | 2 | NO |
| 3 | 2 | YES |
| 1 | 3 | YES |
| 2 | 3 | YES |
| 3 | 3 | NO |

Can someone suggest to me a way to do that?

Comment: are you using mysql or google-bigquery? They're different products.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - and make sure that all data is stored with the correct data type for that data.

Comment: And that said, this is really a display issue, so probably best resolved in application code.

Comment: I am using BigQuery though i've tagged my-sql so that larger audience can be reached as most of the syntax are similar

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan can you help with this?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan the problem is when i try to use extract(week from date), if the particular store was not visited in that week, it will be dropped on using this query and i wont be able to mark yes/no

Comment: @ShashankVats . . . I removed the MySQL tag.  Only tag with the database you are using.  Don't try to game the Stack Overflow site.  I also don't see how dates that are 6 days apart are in different weeks.  How are "weeks" defined"?  And why do you want a string when BigQuery supports boolean values?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which all week you want in your query but you can get all the weeks that are available in your table using following query.

```
select s.store_id, wk.wknum, 
       case when t.store_id is null then 'NO' else 'YES' end as visited
  from (select distinct extract(week from date) wknum from t) wk
cross join (select distinct store_id from t) s
left join t on extract(week from t.date) = wk.wknum and t.store_id = s.store_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
with temp as (
  select store_id, 
    extract(year from parse_date('%d-%m-%Y', date)) year,
    extract(week from parse_date('%d-%m-%Y', date)) week
  from `project.dataset.table`
  group by store_id, year, week
), dates as (
  select extract(year from day) year, extract(week from day) week from (
    select min(parse_date('%d-%m-%Y', date)) min_date, max(parse_date('%d-%m-%Y', date)) max_date
    from `project.dataset.table`
  ), unnest(generate_date_array(min_date, max_date, interval 1 day)) day
  group by year, week
), stores as (
  select distinct store_id from temp
)
select store_id, year, week, if(not t.store_id is null, 'YES', 'NO') as visit
from (select store_id, year, week from dates cross join stores)
left join temp t
using (store_id, year, week)
-- order by store_id, year, week
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]